# grailsLinkGenerator issue in Grails 3 interceptor?

Tags: interceptor, grails-3.0, grails-3.1

I am getting an error in my interceptor for Grails 3.1.4

`The return type of java.lang.Object getGrailsLinkGenerator() incompatible with grails.web.mapping.LinkGenerator in grails.artefact.controller.support.Response Redirect`

The code that I implemented is as follows:

```
response.sendRedirect("${grailsLinkGenerator.link(controller: 'trendingClaimsDemoAndGeographic', action: 'index')}")
```

Answer (score 1):

I've faced similar problem while using Grails 3.1.4.

I guess, you are using `org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.LinkGenerator` which is now deprecated.

---

I fixed it using `grailsLinkGenerator` from the package `grails.web.mapping.LinkGenerator`

Hope this helps.